# How to use an anonymous fifo in a Makefile?

Tags: bash, makefile, pandoc, fifo

Is it possible to use an anonymous fifo in a Makefile?

I tried it the following way:

```
%.html: %.txt
        pandoc -o $@ <(sed 's%•%*%' $<)
```

but I get a syntax error from `/bin/sh`.

1. How can I use an anonymous fifo in a Makefile?
2. Is there a better solution to use a simple regex (or even a simple find and replace) filter for pandoc?

Comment: I do not know enough about makefiles, but `<()` is a process substitution syntax and is not specified by POSIX, and not implemented by all shells.

Comment: In a shell script, you can create a FIFO (`mkfifo`), associate it with a file descriptor (using `exec`), and then delete the file.  The FIFO will remain associated with the file descriptor, and you can use it even if the reference in the filesystem is gone.  I do not know if you can do that from a makefile.

Comment: Makefiles generally use `/bin/sh` and it doesn't understand process substitution. But `pandoc` doesn't require a filename on its command line.  It takes input from stdin if no filenames are specified, so you should be able to use a plain pipe instead: `sed 's%•%*%' "$<" | pandoc -o "$@"`

Comment: @ottomeister: Make this an answer and I will accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Done, and thank you

Comment: Are you trying to pass pandoc a parameter which is *not* the name of the input file?

Comment: You can choose whatever shell you want to use with `make` by setting the `SHELL` make variable; if you want bash instead of the default (sh) for example, add `SHELL = /bin/bash` to your makefile.  However, I recommend writing recipes that don't require bash, if possible, for portability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `make` uses `/bin/sh` to execute commands, and `/bin/sh` does not understand the `<(...)` process substitution syntax.

Luckily, `pandoc` does not require a filename on its command line. If no filenames are specified then `pandoc` reads from its standard input stream, so you should be able to feed it the output of the `sed` command through an ordinary pipe, like this:

```
sed 's%•%*%' "$<" | pandoc -o "$@"
```